# Identifying similar patterns in an image in Java

Tags: java, image, image-processing

Consider I have an image of the following type, how can I identify the dots along from the image file. After getting the co-ordinates for the dots, I want to connect few of the dots, as making a square or triangle.

What approach would be the best for this.?

[edit]:
Also, I do not know  the number of dots and it is not regular, like presence of lines in-between the dots.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a convolution mask through the X*Y space of the image. The mask will be the exact 7x7 (or whatever) dot that you have on the image. You will run the mask by negating the pixels and whatever position of the mask gives you the darkest result will mean that you've found a position on the image where a dot exists.

Store all dot locations in a collection for further processing.

How you can connect those dots in squares and triangles is probably another question.

Comment: Can the convolution mask be applied if the number of dots is unknown. i.e n x m. Or should the no. of dots be known beforehand.?Also the dots are not regular, like presence of lines in-between the dots.

Comment: You'll run the mask through all the X*Y pixels of the image. No need to know anything in advance, just the shape of the dot you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This thema is big and complex -  there is a ton of techiques (Books on that matter are usually about 2 kilos  an $100). In this particular case I would recomment following steps.

1. Binarize image ( retty fast and effective algorythm is Sauvola binarization speeded up by integral images )
2. Find your grid positions with a help of integral image ( Integral image  is computed from original one , where each pixel value is sum of all pixels left and up of it. ) -  pixels on the right and bottom of image give you idea, whether image row or column is empty or not

I use those techniques to prepare images and find text lines in JavaOCR open source project:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/javaocr/